# Jquery add space btw capitalized nonstop words after data is loaded

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var CountryVal;
var StateVal;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ItemCountry').change(function(){
        CountryVal = this.value; // value of the select element
        $("#StateFeeder").html('<img src="/images/mapCountry/AU/ajax-loader.gif" class="IMG-Loading" />');
        $('#StateFeeder').load('/StateFeeder/StateFeeder-Buy.html #StateFeeder-'+CountryVal, function(){
            $('#ItemState').change(function(){
                StateVal = this.value; // value of the select element
                $("#CityFeeder").html('<img src="/images/mapCountry/AU/ajax-loader.gif" class="IMG-Loading" />');
                $('#CityFeeder').load('/Country/'+CountryVal+'/_'+CountryVal+'_suburbs.html #Suburbs-'+StateVal, function(){
                    $('#CityFeeder select').attr('size', '5');
                    $('#CityFeeder select').change(function(){  
                        this.form['CAT_Custom_221342'].value=$(this).val();
                    }); 
                });        
            })
        });
    });
});           
</script>
```

The Jquery above will load dropdown menu from other page into current page and pass value into another input field when user makes selection. The problem is, the option value taken from the #StateFeeder in remote page contains the below format:

```
<option value="Kabardino-BalkarRepublic">Kabardino-Balkar Republic</option>
<option value="Karachay-CherkessRepublic">Karachay-Cherkess Republic</option>
<option value="KareliaRepublic">Karelia Republic</option>
<option value="KomiRepublic">Komi Republic</option>
<option value="MariElRepublic">Mari El Republic</option>
<option value="MordoviaRepublic">Mordovia Republic</option>
```

the values above are nonstop capitalized words and I want them to be formated with spaces in between capital words like below (plz keep the "-" btw words)when they are loaded into the current page, **special concern in #ItemState part: when city values are loaded into #ItemState menu,e.g. "KareliaRepublic" the values(without space "KareliaRepublic") is considered as id so that remote menu can be properly loaded, please format it until this load process completed then process the add space action.** thank you very much:

```
<option value="Kabardino-Balkar Republic">Kabardino-Balkar Republic</option>
<option value="Karachay-Cherkess Republic">Karachay-Cherkess Republic</option>
<option value="Karelia Republic">Karelia Republic</option>
<option value="Komi Republic">Komi Republic</option>
<option value="Mari El Republic">Mari El Republic</option>
<option value="Mordovia Republic">Mordovia Republic</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
value = value.​​replace(/([^-])([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2");
```

Comment: You're throwing away a perfectly useful character there.

Comment: @Blazemonger Yes, but only if it is followed by a capitalized char, so it doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: You misunderstand. If you run your code, you're deleting the last character of the previous word.

Comment: @Blazemonger Oh yes, you're right, my fault. I edited, many thanks!

Comment: thanks sp00m, but your code is not working. thanks anyway...:)

Comment: @wanghaipeng I believe it works, you can [see a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nwR56/). That said, you just have to integrate that regex within your own code of course... Something like `$('option').value($('option').value().​​replace(/([^-])([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2"));`?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to manipulate the value string:

```
var stateVal = this.value.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/BgUFm/

[More on using regular expressions with `.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)